# spherical and hyperbolic triangle definitions with geodesics

Tags: terminology, definition, noneuclidean-geometry

What is the equivalent of "collinear" for points on a geodesic?  Are they just called "cogeodesic" or something?  Since the definition of a Euclidean triangle is "any three noncollinear points connected pairwise by straight line segments", I plan to define a spherical or hyperbolic triangle as "any three noncogeodesic points connected pairwise by geodesics".  Does anyone have a better way of stating this?

Also, as an aside, I noticed that the area formulas for these triangles use "$\angle\alpha + \angle\beta + \angle\gamma$" or simply "$\alpha + \beta + \gamma$".  Since these have a quantitative measure in radians, shouldn't they be "$m\angle\alpha + m\angle\beta + m\angle\gamma$"?  If not, why not?"

Comment: Lines make sense in hyperbolic geometry so there is no need to invent another term.  Why would you want to pollute nice looking formula with these $m\angle$ nonsense?  Just define $\alpha$ etc to get rid of them.

Comment: ^I thought defining the angle as a mathematical object, we just list the angle, but when using the size of the angle, we had to put m for "measure of" beforehand.

Comment: Why not just define $\alpha$ as the measure of the angle you want?  Only the anal-retentives bother with this $m\angle$ business which adds absolutely nothing to the geometry.

Comment: To see why "lines" is the best moniker in both the spherical and hyperbolic settings, see the [gnomonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnomonic_projection) and [projective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami%E2%80%93Klein_model) maps, each of which take spherical and hyperbolic geodesics, respectively, to Euclidean lines in the plane.

Comment: Who told you to require vertices of a triangle to be noncollinear?

Comment: ^If they're collinear then it's a degenerate triangle with no area, a line segment split into 2 smaller line segments.